# How to show all text of very long select option?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I have some very long `<option>`s in a `<select>` box but I don't want the box to be so wide. The problem is that the full text can't be read when I style the box smaller. I was thinking about hovering a copy of the text exactly over the option the mouse pointer is over but only if the text is too long to be fully displayed.

However, if I create a new element, say a `<p>` with jQuery it doesn't have a width until I insert it into the document so I can't decide whether to insert it or not.

Even if I did create it successfully I'm not sure all the styles would be the same.

Is there a way to get this idea working or is there a better way of displaying the complete text of the long `<option>`s in-place?

Comment: If you want to display the text on hover, you could use the option's `title`

Comment: this is pretty close to a duplicate of this, especially with the answers given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043634/html-select-problem

Comment: @J148 I'm doing that for starters but I have to wait for each one to pop-up. I hoping for a nicer solution.

Comment: @DrCord I need all the text to actually be there. Also it would be difficult to truncate evenly with a variable width font.

Comment: Set style to overflow:auto for the select-list and see if you like it. This will cause horizontal scroll if  an option text does not fit in.

Answer (score 2):

what about this?

```
<select id="muchtextselect">
  <option value="" title="This is some long text text This is some long text text This is some long text text ">This is some long text text This is some long text text This is some long text text </option>
  <option value="">Short Text</option>
  <option value="" title="This is some really, really long text">This is some really, really long text</option>
</select>
```

js

```
var maxLength = 15;
$('#muchtextselect > option').text(function(i, c) {
  if (c.length > maxLength) {
    return c.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';  
  }
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/doniyor/wCUA6/77/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm already using a combination of `width` and `title` to get a very similar effect, I just don't like it much!

Answer (score 1):

USE style="width:xx%;"

Example

```
<select name="data"  style="width:50%;">
 <option value="1">Lorem Ipsum</option>
 <option value="3">simply dummy</option>
 <option value="3">text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `<select>` box is too big if it displays all the text. I need it to be a fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Select2 last version with bootstrap :) 
i found it in 2 days

> https://select2.org/

```
{!! Html::style('backend/dist/css/select2.min.css') !!}
{!! Html::style('backend/dist/css/select2-bootstrap.css') !!}
{!! Html::script('backend/dist/js/select2.min.js') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use max-width + text-emphasis css properties.
For more information you can check here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-emphasis.asp

Comment: _The text-emphasis property is not supported in any of the major browsers._ ??? max-width wouldn't help. I need some way of viewing the overly long text, not just hide it.

Comment: So what do you think about overflow hidden by default and overflow visible on hover ?

Comment: Have you tried this? I can't find any combination of `overflow` that will cause the `<option>` text to display outside of the `<select>` element.