# Select option show error when it is using inside table

Tags: html, css, html-table

When we are using Select option inside the table and the option text is very big the select box change it behavior. please see the attachment image file for more clear view.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share more input? Are you trying to say that the select list is not fully shown when the value is bigger than the size of the select drop-down? I am assuming, you are having a fixed width select option. Try adding this style and share your input. <select style="width: auto;">

Comment: It might help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407884/how-to-show-all-text-of-very-long-select-option

Comment: You should provide us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code; you should not use or rely on images to describe your issue (they should reinforce your description of the issue); please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Answer (score 0):

oky i found this issue.
There is some content error issue. thanks for you support friends.